# Finding current connected network interface/adaptor Windows

Tags: c++, c, winapi, networking, multicast

I'm thinking there must be a way to ask windows for information about the network adaptor of the current connected network (available unicast/multicast, is it Wi-Fi, the name, etc)

When I say connected, I mean like the current Wi-Fi connection like windows shows you in the Wi-Fi options - the definition of connected is probably different in the networking world

Even if it's just possible the interface index, because It's easy to look up most other things using `GetAdaptersAddresses()` etc

In case this is an x/y problem: I'm trying to do this as part of writing an mdns client (for academic purposes, I know windows has an mdns api). I'd like to only broadcast and receive on the current Wi-Fi network (for which I think you need to set the `IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP` flag in `setsockopt`) and I also need to then know which IP address to return to the mdns response

I could set `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` but then I would still need to find out which IP to return and everything just becomes conceptually easier if things work on a single network (or so I thought)

Comment: Only **one** connected network? What a nice, simple world. Wish I lived there.

Comment: What if the computer has two wi-fi dongles connected to two wi-fi networks? Or, what if the computer is connected to a wi-fi  network and also plugged into a different network?

Comment: A computer can be connected to multiple networks at the same time, whether they are WiFi or otherwise. `GetAdaptersInfo()`/`GetAdaptersAddresses()` will tell you their types, statuses, IPs, etc. You have to decide for yourself which network you want to associate the socket with. If there is only 1 WiFi adapter, then you have your answer. If there are multiple WiFi adapters, ask the user which one to use. Don't guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetAdaptersAddresses` will give you the list of network interfaces on the system and will tell you what type of interface each of them is.

In the returned `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` list, the `IfType` field tells you the type of the interface, which for wireless will be `IF_TYPE_IEEE80211`.  Then when you find an interface of this type, you can iterate through the list of assigned addresses via the `FirstUnicastAddress` member to join the relevant multicast groups.

```
IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *head, *curr;
IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS *uni;
int buflen, err, i;

buflen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS) * 500;  //  enough for 500 interfaces
head = malloc(buflen);
if (!head) exit(1);
if ((err = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, 0, NULL, head,
                                &buflen)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    char errbuf[300];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, err,
                  0, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf), NULL);
    printf("GetAdaptersAddresses failed: (%d) %s", err, errbuf);
    free(head);
    exit(1);
}
for (curr = head; curr; curr = curr->Next) {
    if (curr->IfType != IF_TYPE_IEEE80211) continue;
    for (uni = curr->FirstUnicastAddress; uni; uni = uni->Next) {
        if (curr->OperStatus == IfOperStatusUp) {
            char addrstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

            inet_ntop(uni->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family, uni->Address.lpSockaddr, 
                      addrstr, uni->Address.iSockaddrLength);
            printf("interface name: %s\n", curr->AdapterName);
            printf("interface address: %s\n", addrstr);
        }
    }
}
free(head);
```

An important note here is that there may be more that one wireless interface active.